# Prove that $A \in L( X,Y ) $

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

This is a homework assignment.

I am not sure if my proof is enough to show that $A \in L(X,Y)$. I proved linearity of A. Boundedness is as follows.

Given: $X = l_1 \qquad Y = l_2,$

$A(x1,x2,...) = (y1,y2,...), \qquad \qquad \text{where}\quad y1=x1, \quad y_n=x_n-x_{n-1},\quad n = 2,3,...$

Boundedness of A: $\quad\exists M: ||Ax_n||_2 \leq M||x_n||_1 $

Operator is continuous iff it is bounded:

$\qquad M ||x_n||_1 \rightarrow 0\quad \Rightarrow\quad ||Ax_n||_2 \rightarrow 0$

$ M ||x_n||_1 \rightarrow 0: \quad M\left(\sum_{i=1} ^\infty \xi_i ^n \right) \rightarrow 0$

$||Ax_n||_2 \rightarrow 0: \quad||y_n||_2\rightarrow 0 \Leftrightarrow ||x_n - x_{n-1}||_2 \rightarrow 0 \Leftrightarrow \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty|\xi_i^n - \xi_i^{n-1}|^2 \right)^{1/2} \rightarrow 0 $

$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty|\xi_i^n - \xi_i^{n-1}|^2 \right)^{1/2} \rightarrow 0  \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^\infty|\xi_i^n - \xi_i^{n-1}| \rightarrow 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^\infty \xi_i ^n \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^\infty\xi_i^{n-1} \Leftrightarrow x_n  \rightarrow x_{n-1}$

Comment: If you already showed the boundedness of the shift-operator, you are done as you can write $A$ as the difference of the identity and the shift operator.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Yes, is the reasoning in the proof valid ?

Comment: Your proof is wrong. $l_2$ convergence does not imply $l_1$ convergence. It is the other way around. Use that to show that the identity and shift operator are continuous and you are done.